Custom Fonts Not Working After Updating Xcode 16 and macOS 15.0.1
I recently updated both Xcode 16 and macOS 15.0.1, and now my custom fonts that were working fine before aren’t showing up when using attributed text. I’ve already double-checked that the fonts are included in my project’s Info.plist under the UIAppFonts key, and they appear correctly in Font Book.
Has anyone else faced this issue after an update?
What steps can I take to resolve it and ensure the custom fonts display correctly?


From the release notes: "Known Issues: Custom app fonts may fail to be listed at the top of the custom fonts list in the Interface Builder inspector. (100908086) (FB11662082) Workaround: Restarting Xcode will force this list to be recreated."

Why is ecmascript-2024 a tag here?

I have the same problem but neither restarting XCode 16 nor rebooting works for me. I tried recompiling (no errors). The fonts are listed in the Font Book and are TTF files downloaded from Google. They are also listed (with file extension) in the info.plist file. I've used custom fonts previously in other projects (earlier XCode) but I can't add new ones to this project which didn't have custom fonts before.

FYI: I am only using plain text - not attributed

Any solution found for this? I am facing the same issue.

Still a problem in XCode 16.2 (Sequoia 15.1.1). Apple has had this on their forums for quite a while now. 18 months at least and it's still just a "known issue". How does anyone deploy apps these days?

Remove fonts from app target in target membership and add it again is worked for me. You guys can try this solution. it might help.

This solves the font issue! The OP should accept this as the correct answer.

It helped once, but I was unable to do it again. Xcode is still the worst IDE on this planet...

its not work for me.

Didn't work for me either. Intel Mac here

Didn't work for me. Appreciate the tip though
